# The Norm of a Differential Form on $\Gamma\backslash\mathbb{H}$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-forms, hyperbolic-geometry, modular-forms, modular-group

Let $\Gamma$ be a normal subgroup of finite index of the modular group $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the upper half-plane.

Let $\phi$ be a cusp form of weight $2$ for $\Gamma$. Then $\omega=Re(\phi(z)dz)$ (the real part of $\phi(z)dz$, if $\phi(z)dz=(u(x,y)+iv(x,y))(dx+idy)$, then $\omega=u(x,y)dx-v(x,y)dy$) is a harmonic $1-$ form on $\mathbb{H}$. It induces a harmonic $1-$ form on $\Gamma\backslash\mathbb{H}$ also denoted by $\omega$.

Let $dv$ be the normalised volume element on $\Gamma\backslash\mathbb{H}$.

If case we have the following integral $$\int_{\Gamma\backslash\mathbb{H}}\|\omega\|^2dv$$
Which norm do they mean ($\|\omega\|$)?

Comment: Huh?  How is quotienting the group $\Gamma$ by the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ defined?  And how do you induce the 1-form from $\mathbb{H}$ to the discrete set $\Gamma$ in order to pass it to the quotient $\Gamma/\mathbb{H}$?

Comment: The notation is $\int_{\Gamma/\mathbb{H}}|\omega|^2$ where $|\omega|^2 = \omega\ \wedge\ \overline{\omega}$. Do you know how $\wedge$ works?

Comment: @user10354138 http://www.numdam.org/item/ASENS_1993_4_26_1_23_0/ page $26$

Comment: @Neilhawking Huh?  I don't see anything about quotienting $\Gamma/\mathbb{H}$.  There is the left quotient of $\mathbb{H}$ by $\Gamma$, $\Gamma\setminus\mathbb{H}$, which is a completely different animal to $\Gamma/\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: @user10354138 the $/$ is missing as I think

Comment: @reuns the exterior product?

Comment: @reuns what do you mean by $\overline{\omega}$?

Comment: The complex conjugate 1-form, here $=\omega$.

Comment: @reuns in this case, can't we take $\|\omega\|^2$ outside the Integral since it is just a number?

Comment: Who said so? Did you find the expression for $\omega\wedge \omega$ or not?

Comment: Also $\phi$ must be a weight $2$ modular form for $\phi(z)dz$ to be $\Gamma$-invariant.

Comment: @reuns the norm of an element is always a positive number. No I have not found the expression for the exterior product of $\omega$ with itself yet.

Comment: @reuns yes it is of weight two

Comment: @reuns http://www.numdam.org/item/ASENS_1993_4_26_1_23_0/ page $26$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your paper they are looking at $$\omega =f(z)dz= f(z)dx+if(z)dy$$ for $f$ a weight 2 cusp form. Then $$\omega\wedge \overline{\omega}= 
(f(z)dx+if(z)dy)\wedge (\overline{f(z)}dx-i\overline{f(z)}dy)
$$
Using bilinearity and $dx\wedge dy=-dy\wedge dx,dx\wedge dx=0$ you get that is
$$ = -2i|f(z)|^2\ \ dx\wedge dy=
-2i y^2|f(z)|^2\ \ \frac{dx\wedge dy}{y^2}
$$
$\frac{dx\wedge dy}{y^2}$ is the area $2$-form and you can check that $y^2|f(z)|^2$ is $\Gamma$ invariant so that $$\|f(z)dz\|^2=\int_{\Gamma\backslash \Bbb{H}} y^2|f(z)|^2\ \ \frac{dx\wedge dy}{y^2}$$ makes sense.

This gives a norm on $S_2(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}))$. For harmonic 1-forms the natural norm is $$\sup_{f\in S_2(SL_2(\Bbb{Z})),\|f\|^2\le 1} |\int_{\Gamma\backslash \Bbb{H}} \omega \wedge \Re( f(z) dz)|$$ Which relates to the Petersson inner product.

Comment: Please not that $\omega=Re(f(z)dz)$ not $\omega=f(z)dz$

Comment: It doesn't change the idea, but the result won't involve $|f(z)|^2$.

Comment: $f(z)dz$ can be written as follows $f(z)dz=(u(x,y)+iv(x,y))(dx+idy)$ Therefore, the real part of $f(z)dz$, denoted by $\omega$, is $u(x,y)dx-v(x,y)dy$, i.e., $\omega=u(x,y)dx-v(x,y)dy$. Am I right?

Comment: $\Re(f(z)dz) = \Re(f(z))dx-\Im(f(z))dy$ where $\Im(f(z))$ is the so-called harmonic conjugate of $\Re(f(z))$.

Comment: In the calculation above there was $i$ and then it is missing

Comment: To be honest, I didn't get the point. Is not it a norm? The integral is $\int_{\Gamma/\mathbb{H}}\|\omega\|^2dv$ not $\int_{\Gamma/\mathbb{H}}\|\omega\|^2$

Comment: What I am explaining is in my answer. The point is obvious, you get a 2-form from a 1-form which obviously gives a norm on **holomorphic** 1-forms if you need some (do you need some?). See also Petersson inner product.

Comment: Yes, I really need. You mean the norm is induced by Petersson inner product